# How to pass driver in TestNG to second test class?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng

I am trying to create a testsuite with TestNG in Java with the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite-TestNG" parallel="none" thread-count="2" preserve-order="true">

    <test name="Basictests">
        <classes>
            <class name="tests.multichannel"></class>
            <class name="tests.TestcasesHelper"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```

I also created a class "TestSetup" for defining `@BeforeTest` and `@AfterTest`.

```
package main;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

public class TestSetup {
    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setup()
    {
        System.out.println("BeforeTest --> Setup");

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", PATH-TO-DRIVER);

        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void teardown()
    {
        System.out.println("AfterTest --> teardown");
        if (driver != null) {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }

    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }
}
```

The testcase-classes are both nearly the same, only names are changed.

The first Testclass is multichannel:

```
package tests;

import main.TestSetup;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class multichannel extends TestSetup {

    @Test(priority = 1)
    void Testcase1() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("MultiChannel --> Testcase 1");
        getDriver().get("http://www.google.de");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }

    @Test (priority = 2)
    void Testcase2 () throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("MultiChannel --> Testcase 2");
        getDriver().get("http://www.testpage.com");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }

    @Test (priority = 3)
    void Testcase3 () throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("MultiChannel --> Testcase 3");
        getDriver().get("http://www.seleniumhq.org");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

The second Testclass is `TestcasesHelper`:

```
package tests;

import main.TestSetup;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestcasesHelper extends TestSetup {

    @Test
    void Testcase1() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("TestcaseHelper --> Testcase 1");
        getDriver().get("http://www.google.de");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }

    @Test
    void Testcase2() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("TestcaseHelper --> Testcase 2");
        getDriver().get("http://www.testpage.com");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }

    @Test
    void Testcase3() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("TestcaseHelper --> Testcase 3");
        getDriver().get("http://www.seleniumhq.org");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }

}
```

In the first testcase all is fine and all steps are executed but in the second case I get a `NullPointerException` cause there is no driver/`getDriver()`. Can someone explain why it is working in the first class but not in the second and how I can resolve this Problem?

The Scenario is a Webpage with different Areas to test where certain Areas are grouped in a test with ist own testclasses. That's why I want to pass the Driver to the next class.

Comment: Nullpointexception occuring because of driver instance. please check are you using same driver instance all time in project

Comment: The goal is to create one driver instance per `<test>` so that it is possible to run them later parallel. There are different tests (methods) per class for a specific testpage and I need to login before I can run the `<test>`. I don't think that it is useful the insert the login-process into the test itself.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

**TestSetup.java**

```
public static WebDriver driver;
```

The driver needs to be static to stay alive.

Unfortunately this is not working for parallel execution of `<test>` with more than one `<class>`in it. In the second `<class>` there is again the `NullPointerException` for the driver.

Answer (score 0):

public static WebDriver driver = null;